# SARSA with Updated Actions

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to gain a better understanding of the Classic SARSA Algorithm. Let us assume Finite MDP which is simple enough so that we can use Tabular methods, so no function approximation. In the SARSA algorithm, we take action A in state S, get reward R and then the new state becomes S'. We then pick an action A' using epsilon-greedy based on current Q-Values, perform the SARSA update rule to update Q(S,A) and then take action A' in S'.

**My Question is the following**: Instead of taking action A' in S', once we have performed the SARSA update on Q(S,A), can we pick a new action A'' for S' using epsilon greedy on the updated Q-Values and take A'' instead. Note that this only matters when S' is the same as S.